# Create a table with integer or numeric(4.0) in dBase width Jet.4

Tags: vb.net, numeric, jet, dbf, dbase

I want to create a table (.DBF file) with an Integer(4) field using Microsoft Jet dBase Provider. There is my code :

```
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim comm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\DBFSamples;Extended Properties=dBASE 5.0;"
    conn.Open()
    comm.Connection = conn
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    'First Solution
    comm.CommandText = "Create table Test8(FirstName Integer,LastName Char(50) )"
    'Second Solution
    'comm.CommandText = "Create table Test10(FirstName Numeric(4,0),LastName Char(50) )"
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("OK")
```

This code creates the FirstName field Numeric(20,5) with the First Solution and Numeric(20,0) with the Second Solution.
Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
field1 Integer(4),
field2 Character(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it with Jet, but you should be able to do with Microsoft Visual Foxpro OleDB Provider instead.

Comment: No, i can't. I tested that provider but Foxpro 2.6 Dos can't recognize  the produced file with the Microsoft Visual Foxpro OleDB Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a Visual Foxpro table? If so, use this syntax to create a table with an Integer column and Character column:

```
 CREATE TABLE MyTableName (MyIntField I, MyCharField C(10))
```

Comment: No, i can't. I tested that provider but Foxpro 2.6 Dos can't recognize the produced file with the Microsoft Visual Foxpro OleDB Provider.

Comment: If the table needs to be Foxpro DOS 2.6 compatibile, then Numeric() is the way to go. Try: CREATE TABLE MyTableName (MyNumField Numeric(6), MyCharField C(10))

Answer (score 0):

Use the following conection:

```
connectionString = @"Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=" + path + ";Collating Sequence=machine;";
```

Download [Microsoft OLE DB Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) and create your query

```
comm.CommandText = "Create table Test10(FirstName Numeric(4,0),LastName Char(50) )"
```